# How do I enable options for installed Ports in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports

I installed the Vim editor using Ports and in the process didn't enable GTK2 or GNOME option. I assume that either these 2 options will let me use `gvim`. Here's my `pkg info vim`:

```
vim-7.4.430_1
Name           : vim
Version        : 7.4.430_1
Installed on   : Sun Sep  7 13:30:57 PHT 2014
Origin         : editors/vim
Architecture   : freebsd:10:x86:32
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : editors
Maintainer     : sunpoet@FreeBSD.org
WWW            : http://www.vim.org/
Comment        : Improved version of the vi editor
Options        :
        ATHENA         : off
        CONSOLE        : on
        CSCOPE         : on
        EXUBERANT_CTAGS: on
        GNOME          : off
        GTK2           : off
        LUA            : on
        MOTIF          : off
        NLS            : on
        PERL           : on
        PYTHON         : on
```

Now, I want to enable either the `GNOME` or `GTK2` option.

I've tried `make deinstall` followed by `make reinstall` but I don't get the dialogs for choosing the options to enable just like I did when I installed Vim the first time. I've also tried `make deinstall` then `make install` but still no go.

Comment: And by running `make config` before `make install`? (in `/usr/ports/editors/vim`)

Comment: @julp Thanks for helping me again. that's what I missed. Make this an answer so I can choose it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeBSD is smart enough to not bother you about port options: if they haven't changed at port level (Makefile), it won't ask you twice for them.

I do not use binary packages but I guess, in your case, that options from your previous installed binary package were kept so the `make config` step was skipped.

Anyway, to force FreeBSD to display the dialog screen to choose your build options, run `make config` before `make install`.

In the same way: to restore default options, it exists `make rmconfig`.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be helpful to add this to the official Handbook...just in case noobs like myself need this info.

Comment: At least, all port "commands" (make targets) are described in [`man 7 ports`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ports&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note, you can also enable ports-wide options by editing `/etc/make.conf`, and the `ports(7)` manpage demonstrates this in example 4:

```
Example 4: Setting Ports Options via make.conf(5)

The following lines present various ways of configuring ports options
via make.conf(5) (as an alternative to, e.g., running “make config”):

# Enable NLS for all ports unless configured otherwise
# using the options dialog.
OPTIONS_SET=            NLS
# Disable DOCS for all ports overriding the options set
# via the options dialog.
OPTIONS_UNSET_FORCE=    DOCS
# Disable DOCS and EXAMPLES for the shells/zsh port.
shells_zsh_UNSET=       DOCS EXAMPLES
```

It also references the `/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.options.mk` file, which documents more options that can be set in the comments at the top of the file.

This kind of configuration is what you'll need if you use a tool like [ports-mgmt/synth](https://github.com/jrmarino/synth), but note, synth has it's own make config file location, which by default should be `/usr/local/etc/synth/LiveSystem-make.conf`, but see the synth(1) manpage's `FILES` section for details.